# IE 11 Codeception selenium capabilities

Tags: php, selenium, internet-explorer-11, codeception

Is any one know about the exact way of defining  configs/capabilities for `IE10` and `IE11` browsers in `codeception`'s `acceptance.suite.yml`?

Below is the way in which I defined;

```
env:
  ie11:
   modules:
     config:
       WebDriver:
         browser: 'internet explorer'
           version: 11.0
```

`ie10:
   modules:
     config:
       WebDriver:
         browser: 'internet explorer'
           version: 10.0

`

Comment: It sounds like you weren't happy with the results you got. What happened? What did you want to happen?

Comment: First I want to see the right selenium capabilities defined for  ie10 and ie11. Currently when I run $php codecept.phar run acceptance --env ie11, this command run ie11 but I am expecting to run what I typed in command

Comment: Sorry, $php codecept.phar run acceptance --env ie11, it runs ie10 rather than ie11